# How to change the dask scheduler and workers?

Tags: python, distributed, dask

I am newbie to dask and distributed. I want to change the dask scheduler instead of localhost to use another address of a server. I didn't find how to do it in the internet.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can just pass the IP of a server into a worker constructor, like it's done it the docs http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/python-advanced.html?highlight=scheduler#worker

```
w = Worker('tcp://{your_ip_here}:8786')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to know which file to modify ?

Comment: How have you setup your project?

Comment: I get this project from an intern, so what I found is a file config.xml which configured to use the server

Comment: When I put my ip address in the config file it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

From the user session's point of view, you connect to the remote Dask scheduler using the client:

```
client = dask.distributed.Client('tcp://machine.ip:port')
```

where you need to fill in the machine's address and port as appropriate. You should *not* be constructing a Worker in your session, I am assuming that you scheduler already has some workers set up to talk to.

Yes, there are also ways to include the default address in config files, including having the scheduler write it for you on start-up, but the XML file you mention is unlikely to be something directly read by Dask. On the other hand, whoever designed your system may have its own config layer.